# Como inserir dados em uma posição de array

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, array

Tenho uma função `salvar` que cria um array e envia os dados via post para o BD, porém antes de enviar os dados eu preciso inserir dados em duas posições do array.

Já tentei com `array_fill` e `array_splice` mas estou travado nessa parte. Alguém poderia dar um auxílio?

O código é este:

```
$('#salvar').on('click', function (e) {

var formSerialize = $('#form').serializeArray();
//formSerialize_splice( $formSerialize, 11, 0, formSerialize('#id_servidor') );
//formSerialize = array_fill_keys ('id_origem','id_servidor');

console.log(formSerialize);

var isValid = $('#form').valid();

if (!isValid) {
    msgValidateForm();
} else {

    var formJson = {};

    $.map(formSerialize, function(n, i){
        formJson[n['name']] = n['value'];
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: window.location.origin + "/cadServidores_db.php?action=salvar",
        type: 'POST',
        data: formJson,
        success: function()
        {
            dialogCreateSuccess(formJson.id_servidor);
        }
    });

}

return isValid;

});
```

E o retorno está ficando assim:

```
0: Object { name: "id_servidor", value: "1102778" }
​
1: Object { name: "nm_servidor", value: "vair" }
​
2: Object { name: "dt_admissao", value: "2019-06-03" }
​
3: Object { name: "dt_nascimento", value: "1917-09-27" }
​
4: Object { name: "nr_cpf", value: "12345678945" }
​
5: Object { name: " lotacao", value: "E305" }
​
6: Object { name: "nm_categoria", value: "COM" }
​
7: Object { name: "nm_cargoGratificado", value: "supervisor" }
​
8: Object { name: "id_cargo", value: "18" }
​
9: Object { name: "fl_ativo", value: "1" }
​
10: Object { name: "id_original", value: "" }
​
11: Object { name: "id_origem", value: "" }
​
length: 12
```

Como faço para inserir  dados nas posições 10 e 11?

Comment: É o `console.log(formSerialize);` que mostra esses dados? Que tipo de dado vc quer inserir?

Answer (score 3):

Use o método `.find()` para buscar o objeto pelo valor da chave `name` e alterar o valor da chave `value` do mesmo objeto:

```
formSerialize.find(x => x.name == 'id_original').value = "valor que vc quer inserir";
formSerialize.find(x => x.name == 'id_origem').value = "valor que vc quer inserir";
```